# Datomic apply predicate to attribute with cardinality many

Tags: datomic, datalog

Say I have a Datomic entity with a many-valued attribute (of numbers, for instance).  How would I return a list of entities whose value doesn't contain a specific number?

As an example,

```
{:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
:db/ident :strs
:db/valueType :db.type/string
:db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
}
```

And I want to find all of the entities whose list doesn't contain the number 1.

```
If I do something like:
[:find ?e :where 
[?e :strs ?v]
(not [(.contains ?v "b")])
]
```

But I have

```
e1 :strs ["a", "b", "c"]
e2 :strs ["a", "b"]
e3 :strs ["h", "i", "j"]
```

then all of the entities are returned because the queries are interpreted as 
"find the entities who have a member of strs that doesn't contain "b"", 
but I need

"find the entities e for which every member does not contain "b"".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values that are `:cardinality/many` in datomic are [still stored as individual values under the hood](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/QmhsIL7tZwI/7oGaiEXKtz4J). So the facts for `e1` in your db are:

```
[[e1 :strs "a" tx]
 [e1 :strs "b" tx]
 [e1 :strs "c" tx]]
```

You can leverage that in your query:

```
'[:find ?e
  :where
  [?e :strs]
  (not [?e :strs "b"])]
```

That will find all of the `?e` whose `:strs` value is not `"b"` for all of the facts in the db.